# My application fails after sometime, if i login my application getting java.net.SocketException incompatible with java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a web application that running on WAS 7.0 that works and will remain up for a couple weeks at a time with no issue. All of a sudden it will start throwing  java.net.SocketException incompatible with java.sql.SQLException when trying to loginmy application against MS SQL 2005. There is no

once i restart the Was Server, it'll get back application to normal mode.

**this is catch block.**

```
        catch ( SocketException exc) {                  
        ActionMessages objMessages = new ActionMessages();
        ActionMessage objMessage = new ActionMessage("Common.SocketException",exc.getMessage());
        objMessages.add("Exception", objMessage);
        saveMessages(request, objMessages);
        saveToken(request);
        return mapping.findForward(FAILURE)
```

$   **This is stack trace.**

```
  SystemErr R java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.SocketException incompatible
  with java.sql.SQLException
  SystemErr     R     at 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.notifyEvent(Unknown Source)
  SystemErr     R    at  
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.notifyPooledConnection(Unknown Source)
  SystemErr     R  at 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.receive(Unknown Source)
  SystemErr     R  at 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.IOBuffer.sendCommand(Unknown Source)
  0000001a SystemErr     R   at 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.sendExecute(Unknown Source)
  0000001a SystemErr     R    at
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteQuery(Unknown Source)
  0000001a SystemErr     R   at 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
  0000001a SystemErr     R    at            
  com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery
 (WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1027)
  0000001a SystemErr     R    at 
 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:654)
  0000001a SystemErr     R     at
 com.Login.LoginForm.getHiddenRunningText(LoginForm.java:52)
 [ 0000001a SystemErr     R   at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
 0000001a SystemErr     R   at 
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 0000001a SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be stale connections due to network inactivity.

Comment: why this exception is coming?is that related to the code or the server?

Comment: The driver is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has only one catch block which is for 'java.net.SocketException'.
When SQLException is raised, your program handle that exception by the catch block for SocketException, but the type of SQLException does not match the type of SocketException.
This may be the senario occured on your code.

To handle your situation, your code needs catch block for 'java.sql.SQLException' as below.

```
catch ( SocketException exc) { 
   ...code for SocketException
}
catch ( Exception exc) { // catch block for exceptions except Socket Exception
   ...code for unexpected exceptions
}
```

To prepare catch block for unexpected exceptions in every code is good practice for easy troubel shooting.